Is it possible to temporarily block internet connection to a specific program? preferably with a keyboard hotkey
I was wondering if there is any third-party application that would make it possible for me to temporarily sever internet connection to a specified application? My hope is to use a key bind for this action.
I thought my best option for this would be the standard windows firewall by creating a new rule in the outbound connections tab. However, the main issue is having to manually enable/disable the rule by going into the firewall window.
I've also tried this previous post but the application suggested still requires you to manually enable/disable.

You have two different steps: Creating a keyboard shortcut to do something, and then a script or utility that allows enabling/disabling internet access for a given application. What research have you done so far regarding these steps? What have you tried?

You may also disable and enable a firewall rule from the command-line.
You could create two .bat files on the desktop for that and assign each
a keyboard shortcut. Alternatively, use
AutoHotkey
to run the commands on these shortcuts.
The commands to use would be:
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="MyRule" new enable=no
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="MyRule" new enable=yes

(Note: I have seen cases where name="MyRule" didn't work but
group="MyRule" did work, depending on the rule definition.)
In PowerShell you could use the
Disable-NetFirewallRule command
and the
Enable-NetFirewallRule command.
